# How can I save EntityFramework Model inside itself?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, savechanges

I have a model, called User (derived from my database) and I'm adding methods inside the partial class, allowing the User object to do maintenance type work.

As an example, I would like my application to update the user's SupervisorID in its database in alignment with another database:

```
public partial class User
{
    DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
    OtherEntities otherDB = new CommonEntities();

        public void UpdateSupervisor()
        {
            // Lookup the Supervisor's Username in the other Database:
            string supervisorUsername = (from x in otherDB.vwEmployees
                                 join y in otherDB.vwEmployees on x.Supervisor_EID equals y.Employee_ID
                                 where x.User_ID == searchUsername
                                 select y.User_ID).FirstOrDefault();

            // Update the database to record the Supervisor of this staff member:
            this.SupervisorUserID = (from x in db.Users
                                     where x.ADUsername == supervisorUsername
                                     select x.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

            // At this point, this.SupervisorUserID stores the correct int, but the following command doesn't save any changes.
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

The code works, except that the db.SaveChanges() doesn't save anything (no errors).

The method is called outside of this class, as part of login processing:

```
public class Login {
// Connect to the database:
DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

User currentUser = new User();

// Do some stuff...

// Update the user's supervisor:
currentUser.UpdateSupervisor();
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Russell

Comment: is the same instance of `DatabaseEntities` like `db` used? Otherwise it would not detect any changes since `db` is only used to get data in the code you've posted. If `this` is received using another instance it won't work.

Comment: Updated the question - I hope it is more clear.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your db object inside your class is different from the one in your program that is calling this method. Also, your user object might not exist in the database. So, it isn't as simple as setting the property and then saving.

You will have to pull the item using your db object inside the class and then update or add accordingly.

```
public partial class User
{
    DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
    OtherEntities otherDB = new CommonEntities();

        public void UpdateSupervisor()
        {
            // Lookup the Supervisor's Username in the other Database:
            string supervisorUsername = (from x in otherDB.vwEmployees
                                         join y in otherDB.vwEmployees on x.Supervisor_EID equals y.Employee_ID
                                         where x.User_ID == searchUsername
                                         select y.User_ID).FirstOrDefault();

            // Update the database to record the Supervisor of this staff member
            this.SupervisorUserID = (from x in db.Users
                                     where x.ADUsername == supervisorUsername
                                     select x.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

            // Find user in DBContext using your primary key...
            var user = db.Users.Find(this.ID);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // User exists in database, update id
                user.SupervisorUserID = this.SupervisorUserID;
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not exist in database
                db.Users.Add(this);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: Updated the question to help - the method is within the User class, a partial class that matches up with the User class created by EF from my database.  Inside the class, I don't create an instance of user, because I'm already in the class - hence the "this" syntax.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Even still, I believe the context inside of your user class is different from the context you might be using when you create the object in your other method.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on the difference between context and Entities...   I updated the code again - both classes utilize DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities(); to connect to the database.  I don't have any code that includes the word "Context".  :-)   Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this - I was able to save a User within the User Partial class, by creating a User inside the user:

```
public partial class User
{
    DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
    OtherEntities otherDB = new CommonEntities();

        public void UpdateSupervisor()
        {
            // Lookup the Supervisor's Username in the other Database:
            string supervisorUsername = (from x in otherDB.vwEmployees
                                 join y in otherDB.vwEmployees on x.Supervisor_EID equals y.Employee_ID
                                 where x.User_ID == searchUsername
                                 select y.User_ID).FirstOrDefault();

            // Update the database to record the Supervisor of this staff member:
            this.SupervisorUserID = (from x in db.Users
                                     where x.ADUsername == supervisorUsername
                                     select x.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
            // NEW CODE:
            // Create a new user inside the User class, set to the current User by ID:
            User tempUser = db.Users.Find(this.UserID);
            tempUser.SupervisorUserID = this.SupervisorUserID;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.  :-)

Russell